# Send mail and Add followers not working for all users of Odoo

Tags: email, odoo, odoo-8

The scenario goes like this:

Email setup for outgoing mail server has been done with email address like help@companydomain.com(example) and configured it.

Under General settings, I have used alias domain as companydomain.com. Also I have set email aliases for each user.

Now any user has set his email as help@companydomain.com can send mails and add followers(Add followers will drop a mail to followers) and the mails are received to any email client like thunderbird .

But when other users send mail, it does not deliver to email client like thunderbird and outlook.

Pretty much confused on how to configure the outgoing email gateway server in odoo. Any suggestions would really be helpful.

Comment: you check it you setup the outgoing mail service in odoo.